# How get all li below div content selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can i get all `<a>` value?

```
<div id="mCSB_1_container" class="mCSB_container" style="position: relative; top: -985px; left: 0px;" dir="ltr">
  <li>
    <a href="#" rel="" class="" style="background-color: rgb(247, 247, 249);">All countries</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#217" rel="217" class="">Germany</a>
  </li>
<div>
```

When i use

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='mCSB_1_container']/li/a"));
        for (WebElement element: allElements) {
            System.out.println(element.getText());
        }
```

i get empty values.

Comment: It should work. Are this codeblock inside a iframe? If yes, I can post how handle the situation

Comment: @StriterAlfa you can check full screen on http://rgho.st/6SLnStRYB

Comment: Try to insert this script in chrome console: `$("iframe #mCSB_1_container li a")` and tell me if it returns any result. Also, inserts `$x("//div[@id='mCSB_1_container']/li/a")`, it will test your xpath in chrome using the console.

Comment: @StriterAlfa http://rgho.st/62XRlPXqd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of below selectors:

```
By.xpath("//div[@id='mCSB_1_container']/li/a")
By.cssSelector("#mCSB_1_container li a")
By.cssSelector("div[id='mCSB_1_container'] li a")
By.xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'mCSB_1_container')]/li/a")
```

Or one of this findElements (I don't know if Java contains FindElements extension to IWebElement, but it work in other languages):

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver
    .findElement(By.id("mCSB_1_container"))
    .findElements(By.cssSelector("li a"));

List<WebElement> allElements = driver
    .findElement(By.id("mCSB_1_container"))
    .findElements(By.tagName("a"));

List<WebElement> allElements = driver
    .findElement(By.id("mCSB_1_container"))
    .findElements(By.xpath("//li/a"));
```

Also, if no one works, try to find when breaks, using something like:

```
By.cssSelector("#mCSB_1_container")    //Shoud find the id. 
By.cssSelector("#mCSB_1_container li") //Shoud find the li inside the id.
```

If is unable to find one of they, there is some problem with frames or wait the element display

Comment: i use all ways that you offered me, but no one return text. you can check screens http://rgho.st/8yqVN9Hw5

Comment: Instead of `.getText()` use `.getAttribute("innerHTML")`, it will work.  I thinked your list of webelements was empty

Answer (score 1):

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
     for(WebElement element: allElements)
    {
        System.out.println(element.getText());
    }
```

Comment: ok, this code get ALL <a> tags in page, but I need to get all <a> in <div>

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup is a great html parser and it can be used with Selenium.
here is the Jsoup web page; https://jsoup.org/

and if you want to get **all** links from page you can use Jsoup like that;

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://jsoup.org/").get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

for (Element link : links) {
            print(link);
        }
```

this code snippet allows you to get all href values of all links. if you want to get all  from web page use ;

```
Elements links = doc.select("a");
```

instead of

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
```